# substring/regex to get a src value held in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string with the value:

```
var string = "<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>"
```

I'd like to take the `URL` held in the `src` attribute part of the string if possible.

How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: use variant of preg_match_all, http://regexr.com?324la

Answer (score 43, accepted):

One way to do it is to use regular expressions.

```js
var str = "<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>";

var regex = /<img.*?src='(.*?)'/;
var src = regex.exec(str)[1];

console.log(src);
```

Comment: I think people in general disagree with the idea of using regular expressions to parse html. But this seems to be a simple case.

Comment: Yeah without much information as to what hes doing though its really hard to say what he should using.

Comment: This regex is incomplete. What if `str = "<img></img><script src='url'>"`?

Comment: minor addition (img src="url"), to accept double quotation for src: `var regex = /<img.*?src=['"](.*?)['"]/;`

Answer (score 7):

Alternative method if its always going to be html data.

```
var string ="<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>";

var elem= document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = string;

var images = elem.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++){
   console.log(images[i].src);   
}
​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Zaaqy/)**

Answer (score 7):

One approach, is the following:

```
var string = "<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>",
    srcWithQuotes = string.match(/src\=([^\s]*)\s/)[1],
    src = srcWithQuotes.substring(1,srcWithQuotes.length - 1);
console.log(src);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DmhZb/).

This effectively matches a sequence of characters starting with `src=` (the `=` is escaped with a back-slash because, otherwise, it holds special meaning within regular expressions), followed by a sequence of non-white-space characters (`^\s*`) followed by a white-space character (`\s`).

This expression explicitly captures the quotes used to delimit the `src` attribute, the `src` is returned by taking a substring of the `srcWithQuotes` variable, starting at `1` (the first, the zeroeth, character should be the attribute delimiter) until the index before the last character (the final quote delimiting the attribute).

There is a slightly convoluted  (but potentially more reliable) approach, using a document fragment:

```
var string = "<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>",
    temp = document.createElement('div'),
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

temp.innerHTML = string;
frag.appendChild(temp);
console.log(temp.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src);​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DmhZb/1/).

Of course, in this example, you could use any approach you like to find the image within the `temp` node (`getElementById()`, `getElementsByClassName()`...).

Comment: What if there are no space after the quotes. i.e.: `/UID'/>`?

Comment: This is a great solution and worked well for me. Until the editors in the Wordpress blog that I am pulling the content via a JSON feed use apostrophes in their alt tag descriptions - that effectively breaks the string. I don't think it has anything to do with this code - it's the JSON feed.

Answer (score 5):

Native DOM (will result in GETs)

```
var str = "<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>",
d = document.createElement('div'),
srcs = [];
d.innerHTML = str;
srcs = Array.prototype.slice.call(d.querySelectorAll('[src]'),0);
while( srcs.length > 0 ) console.log( srcs[0].src ), srcs.shift();
```

or RegExp

```
var str = "<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>",
re = /\ssrc=(?:(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")|([^\s]*))/i, // match src='a' OR src="a" OR src=a
res = str.match(re),
src = res[1]||res[2]||res[3]; // get the one that matched

src; // http://api.com/images/UID
```

Comment: Good approach but I had an error when was matching this string `<img class="avatar-48" src="" />`, `src` was `undefined||""||undefined = undefined`

Comment: I think that this should be the regex now`/\ssrc=(?:(?:'([^']+)')|(?:"([^"]+)")|([^'"\s][^\s\/>]*))/i`.I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbg9dp97/1/) to test it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to match specifically the `src` property in an `<img>` tag.
You can use this Regex because it will match the tag, still preserve other properties it might have and also other content inside the `src` property:

`var matches = string.match(/<img([^>]+)src="[/]?([^"]+)"([^>]*)>|<( *)img( *)[/>|>]/g);`

it can be improved but works fine with some varieties of typing.

for example, if you want to match `<img>` or even `<img src="/200px-Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg.png" alt="" width="100" height="172" />` to add something to the url, you can do the following replacement:

`string.replace(/<img([^>]+)src="[/]?([^"]+)"([^>]*)>|<( *)img( *)[/>|>]/g, '<img $1src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/99/Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg/$2" $3>');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this, using the find method, get the src attribute of the image.

```
var str = '<img src="/uploads/thumbnail/79a23278ec18b2fc505b06ab799d5ec672094e79.jpg">';

var result = $(str).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');  //  get a image src
```

Answer (score -2):

Faccy 2015: Using jQuery and CofeeScript via DOM

```
str = '<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>'

img = $(@.content).find('img').each ()->
  srcimg = $(@).attr('src')
  console.log srcimg
```