# To find the value of src in a string

Tags: javascript

I have the following string

```
  "<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DgPO56ImqUA?showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>".
```

how can i get the value of src using javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [substring/regex to get a src value held in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393671/substring-regex-to-get-a-src-value-held-in-a-string)

Comment: @Ashok do you have a string or a HTML element can you please clarify

Comment: before moving forward do check if your string is valid or not. It should be var srcString = "<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/DgPO56ImqUA?showinfo=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"; OR var srcString1 = "<iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/DgPO56ImqUA?showinfo=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";

Comment: If you have a `string` of HTML that contains `"` characters, you'll need to either escape them (eg: `"<iframe width=\"420\">"`) or use a different string-delimiter to surround the whole thing (eg: single-quotes: `'<iframe width="420">'`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to pull the `src` from your string like so:

```
var myString = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DgPO56ImqUA?showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
var regex = /<iframe.*?src="(.*?)"/;

var src = regex.exec(myString)[1];

console.log(src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your frame such as

"name="frame1" width=..... />"

then use this 
alert(document.frames['frame1'].location.href);