# Find all image src url in string and store in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var rawString = '<a>This is sample</a><img src="example1.com" /></br><img src="example2.com" /><p>String ends.</p>'

var output = somefunction(rawString);
```

output should be:

> output = ["example1.com","example2.com"];

I didn't find any solution here. I tried using few regex but couldn't work perfactly.

Here are stackoverflow few answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12393724/4203409

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25632187/4203409

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Using Javascript and regex:

```
function getAttrFromString(str, node, attr) {
    var regex = new RegExp('<' + node + ' .*?' + attr + '="(.*?)"', "gi"), result, res = [];
    while ((result = regex.exec(str))) {
        res.push(result[1]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var rawString = '<a>This is sample</a><img src="example1.com" /></br><img src="example2.com" /><p>String ends.</p>';
getAttrFromString(rawString, 'img', 'src');
```

Returns:

```
["example1.com", "example2.com"]
```

Here is your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mwfu63r/1/)

Comment: If you change the order in node `img` attributes not work. For example: `var rawString = '<a>This is sample</a><img alt="test1" src="example1.com" /></br><img alt="test2" src="example2.com" /><p>String ends.</p>';`

Comment: @Joaquinglez fixed! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use `jQuery()`, `.filter()`, `.map()`, `.get()`

```
var output = $(rawString).filter("img").map(function() {return this.src}).get();
```

Comment: thanks 
I tried with given data:

<style></style><div><div>
<div class=''   >
<div class="">
<div style=position:relative>
<div id="" class=sideCross >X </div>
<div class="vertical-text">Live Chat</div>
  <img src="abcExample.com" alt="text" />
<div class=speech-bubble></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>

NOT WORKING.. :(

Comment: Your string is not in well formate. Many class are not quoted(' ', " ") and the inner string should be same quoted not both (' ' ," "). You have to use var string ="<div class=\"test-class\"></div> to make your string proper in case of same inner and out quoted. Please correct your string. Pls see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

.Filter work with this example

```
var rawString = '<a>This is sample</a><img src="example1.com" /></br><img src="example2.com" /><p>String ends.</p>';
var  indices = new Array();
        var result = $(rawString).filter('img').map(function() {
            indices.push(this.src);
        });
        console.log(indices);
```

.find Will work with this example

```
var rawString = "<style></style><div><div><div class=''><div class=''><div style='position:relative'><div id='' class='sideCross'>X</div> <div class=\"vertical-text\">Live Chat</div><img src=\"http://localhost/rcm/dashboard\" alt=\"text\"/><div class=\"speech-bubble\"><img src=\".com\" alt=\"text\"/></div></div></div></div></div> </div>";
        var  indices = new Array();
        var result = $(rawString).find('img').map(function() {
            indices.push(this.src);
        });
        console.log(indices);
```