# Is there any way to extract image src attribute from the tinymce?

Tags: angularjs, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor

I am new to angular js and I'm using tinymce in one of my projects.In the editor they can upload any no. of images . I want to check if there is any way to extract all the images using angularJs or tinymce plugin.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce ?

Comment: yes. I am using that one only

Comment: Ok, what exactly you mean by saying "extract images"? Which logical part of a image is needed?

Comment: I want the image src to be extracted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all image src attributes by using `regex`. This simple [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wno79hem/3/) shows you how to make it work with tinymce. I've took the `getAtttrFromString()` function from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247923/find-all-image-src-url-in-string-and-store-in-array).

```
function getAttrFromString(str, node, attr) {
    var regex = new RegExp('<' + node + ' .*?' + attr + '="(.*?)"', "gi"), result, res = [];
    while ((result = regex.exec(str))) {
        res.push(result[1]);
    }
    return res;
}

var arrayOfImageSrcs = getAttrFromString(
  '<img src="http://placekitten.com/350/300"><img src="http://placekitten.com/350/300">', 
  'img', 
  'src'
);
```

Comment: @Lucifer glad to help ya. Cheers